# Updated TWebBrowser now implements IDocUIHandler from the start, how can I keep using my custom implementation?

Tags: delphi, com, ole, twebbrowser, shdocvw

Beginning with Delphi 10.0 Seattle, Embarcadero has changed the implementation of the `TWebBrowser` control:

Pre-Seattle: `TWebBrowser = class(TOleControl)`

Seattle+: `TWebBrowser = class(TOleControl, IDocHostUIHandler, IDocHostShowUI, IOleCommandTarget)`

I have somewhat old code running where I had implemented a class that could register as a client site/host for a `TWebBrowser` where I provided my own implementation of the `IDocHostUIHandler` interface.

Since a `TWebBrowser` is now implementing these from the start (and keeping them private) and is hard to descend from for all I know - how do I go about to get the new `TWebBrowser` component to re-register where to find an implementation for `IDocHostUIHandler`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest either to use an earlier version of ShDocVw.Pas, or simply create your own import unit for the webbrowser?  You don't have to use the Delphi-supplied one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can descend from TWebBrowser and provide your own interface definitions as before, like this:

```
Type
  TMyWebBrower = class( TWebBrowser, IDocHostUIHandler )
  ...
  end;
```

This tells Delphi that you are reimplementing the IDocHostUIHandler interface. You must provide all functions for the interface, but you already have that.

Comment: That's the solution I settled with, and it indeed works!